# How is this infinite list computed?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

The problem is the following:

> Define a Haskell variable dollars that is the infinite list of amounts
>   of money you have every year, assuming you start with $100 and get
>   paid 5% interest, compounded yearly. (Ignore inflation, deflation,
>   taxes, bailouts, the possibility of total economic collapse, and other
>   such details.) So dollars should be equal to: [100.0, 105.0, 110.25,
>   ...].

My solution is the following and it works:

```
 dollars::[Double]
 dollars = 100.0 : [1.05 * x | x<- dollars ]
```

The problem is that I have trouble understanding how the list is computed practically:

```
dollars= 100.0 : [1.05 * x | x<- dollars ] 
= 100.0 : [1.05 * x | x<- 100.0 : [1.05 * x | x<- dollars ]   ]
= 100.0 : (1.05 * 100.0) : [1.05 * x | x<- [1.05 * x | x<- dollars ]    ]
= 100.0 : 105.0 : [1.05 * x | x<- [1.05 * x | x<- dollars ]   ]
= 100.0 : 105.0 : [1.05 * x | x<- [1.05 * x | x<-  100.0 : [1.05 * x | x<- dollars ]  ]  ]
= 100.0 : 105.0 : [1.05 * x | x<- 105.0:[1.05 * x | x<-[1.05 * x | x<- dollars ]  ]  ]
= 100.0 : 105.0 : 110.25 :[1.05 * x | x<-[1.05 * x | x<-[1.05 * x | x<- dollars ]  ]  ]
```

etc.

Is that how it is computed? If not then how? If yes, is there a simpler way to conceptualize these kinds of computations?

Answer (score 2):

You are pretty much correct. It might help if you de-sugared the list comprehension into a function call. The equivalent is

```
dollars = 100.0 : map (* 1.05) dollars
```

This then evaluates to

```
= 100.0 : let dollars1 = 100 * 1.05 : map (*1.05) dollars1 in dollars1
= 100.0 : 105.0 : let dollars2 = 105 * 1.05 : map (*1.05) dollars2 in dollars2
```

and so on. I'm using `dollars1`, `dollars2` as identifiers, even though they don't really exist.

Answer (score 0):

That is more or less correct. In which order the substitutions happen depends on the code that prints out the results. The substitutions in the 2. and 3. line could be swapped.